# Java JInternalFrame dispose find source

Tags: java, jinternalframe

I have a JInternalFrame which could be closed by clicking on the X button or programmatically from the menu. Both approaches end up in

```
public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e)
```

and later

```
public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent e)
```

I would like to distinguish the source of this call and trigger different actions (i.e. in the case of closing my frame by X button ask for confirmation and later dispose(), in the case of selecting "close" from the menu just dispose() the frame).

Could you suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the behavior of the X button, you may set the default close operation to `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`, and add an `InternalFrameListener` which will take care of asking for closing confirmation, and closing the frame if needed :

```
        internalFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        internalFrame.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameListener() {

            @Override
            public void internalFrameOpened(final InternalFrameEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void internalFrameClosing(final InternalFrameEvent e) {

                // Do your confirmation stuff !!
                // Dispose the internal frame if needed !!

            }

            @Override
            public void internalFrameClosed(final InternalFrameEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void internalFrameIconified(final InternalFrameEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void internalFrameDeiconified(final InternalFrameEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void internalFrameActivated(final InternalFrameEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void internalFrameDeactivated(final InternalFrameEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

> **DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE**
>
> Do nothing. This requires the program to handle
>   the operation in the windowClosing method of a registered
>   InternalFrameListener object.

(note that in the above documentation extract, I suspect that `windowClosing` is a typo, they probably meant `internalFrameClosing`) .

See : [JInternalFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int))

Comment: Thank you. I already have this structure and DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE is also enabled. Still, I would like to distinguish if the call to the method internalFrameClosing came from X button or from other method (e.g. by calling internalFrame.dispose();)

Comment: I just tested , calling `dispose` will call `internalFrameClosed` , but will NOT call `internalFrameClosing` , so you know that the `internalFrameClosing` call only comes from the X button, if your programmatical closing is always performed by a call to `dispose`..